# Linq query w/ Entity Frameworks

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I am using Entity frameworks and Linq to post results to a telerik Gridview. This is all just to learn the different ways of how to work w/Entity frameworks and Linq. Previously I was using worded linq queries w/ a master view class to return results to the telerik grid, now trying to pick up the lambda notation w/ anonymous type return.

When I put a breakpoint on my 'result' variable, I can see that I have 33 rows. However when I bind it to my Telerik Grid, it shows 4 pages of gridview with empty rows.

Here is what my Telerik Gridview looks like on Aspx page:-

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="gvwData" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" AllowFilteringByColumn="true" OnNeedDataSource="gvwData_NeedDataSource">
    <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns ="false" TableLayout="Fixed">
        <ColumnGroups>
            <telerik:GridColumnGroup Name="GeneralInfo" HeaderText="Offender Information" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
            <telerik:GridColumnGroup Name="BillingInfo" HeaderText="Billing Information" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </ColumnGroups>
        <HeaderStyle Width="200px" />
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridNumericColumn DataField = "Offender.YouthNumber" HeaderText="Offender ID" HeaderStyle-Width="100px" FilterControlWidth="50px" ColumnGroupName="GeneralInfo"/>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression ="Offender.LastName" DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" ColumnGroupName="GeneralInfo">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Offender.FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" ColumnGroupName="GeneralInfo"/>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Offender.DateOfBirth" HeaderText="DOB" ColumnGroupName="GeneralInfo"/>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Violations.PoliceReportDate" HeaderText="Report Date" ColumnGroupName="GeneralInfo"/>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Fee.Amount" HeaderText="Payment Owed" ColumnGroupName="BillingInfo"/>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
    <PagerStyle AlwaysVisible="true" Mode="NumericPages"/>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Here is what my Code-behind looks like:-

```
using (var ctx = new Data.Model.TrackingEntities())
{
    var result = ctx.Offenders
        .Join(ctx.Fees, Offenders => Offenders.OffenderId, Fees => Fees.OffenderId,
        (Offenders, Fees) => new { Offenders = Offenders, Fees = Fees })
        .Join(ctx.ViolationOffenders, Offenders => Offenders.Offenders.OffenderId, ViolationOffenders => ViolationOffenders.OffenderId, 
        (Offenders, ViolationOffenders) => new { Offenders = Offenders, ViolationOffenders = ViolationOffenders })
        .Join(ctx.Violations, Violations => Violations.ViolationOffenders.ViolationId, ViolationOffenders => ViolationOffenders.ViolationId,
        (Violations, ViolationOffenders) => new { Violations = Violations, ViolationOffenders = ViolationOffenders }).ToList();

    gvwData.DataSource = result;
}
```

Q1) Can anyone tell me why I have results in the variable, and the gridview shows 4 pages of info, yet nothing is displayed. However if I eliminate the final 2 joins, I get rows displayed in the gridview.

Q2) Is there a better way to write the linq statements with so many joins? I would be happy to learn new/more compact ways of writing these long joining linq statements.

Comment: You should be using classes with Navigation properties.  Then you just write: `var result=ctx.Offenders.Include(o=>o.Fees).Include(o=>o.VioloationOffenders).Include(o=>o.Violations);`  and you should usually skip the `.ToList()` unless that is a requirement of Telerix's Grid.  Actually, if you made `ctx` a controller level variable, then you could probably just use `var result=ctx.Offenders();`

Comment: Without the `.ToList()`, telerix's grid should (may?) pull in the extra data because you referenced it all on it's own, but I'm unfamiliar with it, so I'd just be guessing based on how other stuff works.

Comment: If you get an error about the .Include or that it can't convert a delegate type to a string, make sure you put a `using System.Data.Entity;` at the top of your file.

Comment: @RobertMcKee no errors Robert.

Comment: @RobertMcKee thanks for the pointer to the include statement. I will look into it.

Comment: so figured out the issue, I guess since I have so many joins in my linq, my datafield for the gridview is now 3 levels deep.... Violations.Offenders.Offenders.FirstName.... :) cheers.

Comment: Ah yes, I see that now.  It was the first Join that was doing it to you.  You were returning an anonmous object that had two properties.. Offenders and Fees, and things just got worse from there.

Comment: Yep. But looks like using include will automatically allow entity framework to use its navigational properties for the join.. instead of writing the long Linq Query.

Comment: That is correct Philo.  If you use the include, EF will use the navigation properties to generate all the joins for you.  Just like I had in my first comment.  Your giant join mess just turns into `var result=ctx.Offenders.Include(o=>o.Fees).Include(o=>o.VioloationOffenders).Includ‌​e(o=>o.Violations);` or possibly just `var result=ctx.Offenders;` depending on how telerix's grid tries to access the data.

Comment: @RobertMcKee Thanks Robert. I get a syntax error on the last lambda expression o => o.Violations... it says cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because its not a delegate type

Comment: Please read the 3rd comment.

Comment: I already have that. lol.

Comment: @RobertMcKee Its strange that my lambda expression recognizes all other entity classes except for the Violation...

Comment: Does your offenders class have a navigation property named Violations?

Comment: Looks like it needs to be something like 0 = > O.ViolationOffenders.Violation... but that is not the correct syntax

Comment: Can you post your offender and violation classes?

Comment: Violation class:-
  
        public virtual ICollection<Victim> Victims { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ViolationOffender> ViolationOffenders { get; set; }
...
Violation Offender class:-

        public virtual Offender Offender { get; set; }
        public virtual Violation Violation { get; set; }
...
Offender class :-

        public virtual ICollection<Fee> Fees { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ViolationOffender> ViolationOffenders { get; set; }

...
So to get to violations, offenders must be joined to violationoffenders and then get violations

Comment: try `.Include(o=>o.ViolationOffenders.Select(of=>of.Violation)))`  normally a cross reference table like ViolationOffenders is hidden in the model, and offenders has a direct virtual collection of Violations, but that doesn't seem to be the case for you.